# Android: linebreak not working in textview

Tags: android, tags, textview

I'm having a string array:

```
String[] articles = getArticles();

// articles[0] = "1. With the mixtures&lt;br />2. Colors and others&lt;br />";
// articles[1] = "3. Categories and people&lt;br />4. Health and fitness";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (String text : articles) {
   sb.append(text);
}

String content = sb.toString();
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(content);

textView.setText(spanned);
```

The problem is that in the `textView` I'm getting HTML tags, instead of applying the line break.

```
1. With the mixtures<br />2. Colors and others<br />3. Categories and people<br />4. Health and fitness
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
articles[0] = "1. With the mixtures&lt;<br />2. Colors and others&lt;<br />";
// articles[1] = "3. Categories and people&lt;<br />4. Health and fitness";
```